# Import-CSV and search the results

Tags: powershell

I want to import a CSV file with two columns (username, date).

I want to search for a specific string (user) and have it return the date of that user that is stored in the column next to it.

thank you very much.

Comment: Go on, you know what you want. Now do it.

Answer (score 12):

This should do it:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\test.csv
$csv | where {$_.username -eq "Tim"} | % date
```

Comment: I will need to import the CSV once and do multiple searches on it is there a better way to do it then importing it every time?

Comment: Updated the answer for this new requirement.